# Is there an application that can automatically set Graphics Properties when docking?

Tags: windows, multiple-monitors, display, script

I have a dual display setup with my laptop (Dell, with integrated graphics, WinXP). The problem is that whenever I hook up the laptop to the monitor I have to go to Graphics Properties (Intel Graphics Media Driver for Mobile) and set the display resolution, window position, etc. Note that this screen is different than the built-in one you usually see in WinXP.

1) Is there an app that can save display settings properly so they will come back when I dock again?

2) Barring this, run a script or a macro to automatically set up the display the way I want it.

3) Or, can I write a .Net program that does this for me?

Extra points if there is an Open source app that can do this.

Answer (score 0):

Well, reminds me the terrific mac [MarcoPolo](http://www.symonds.id.au/marcopolo/) application. We don't have (according to [AlternativesTo](http://alternativeto.net/software/marcopolo/)
) a total equivalent. However, it seems like [Quick Config](http://intelloware.com/en/QuickConfig.aspx) contains quite all you need. Maybe by dropping a line at company/author he could give you what you need ...